# Compact operators form the only closed proper ideal of bounded linear operators

Tags: functional-analysis, ideals, spectral-theory, compact-operators

I am trying to understand the following proof in *Trace Ideals and Their Applications* by Barry Simon (Proposition 2.1):

Let $\mathcal{J}$ be a two-sided ideal in $\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$ containing an operator $A$ which is not compact. Then $\mathcal{J} = \mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$.

I have two main questions about the proof. First of all, the author uses the spectral decompositon of $|A|$ and that 
$$
|A| = \lim_{a\to 0} |A|P_{[a,\infty]}
$$
He then claims that if all the $P_{[a,\infty]}$ were finite dimensional, $|A|$ would be compact. Why is this?

The other question: the author uses that fact that for an infinite dimensional spectral projection $P_{[a,\infty]}$, there exists an isometry $V$ from $\mathscr{H}$ onto $\text{Ran} \, P_{[a,\infty]}$ and does not give a proof. I have no idea where I can find this.

I would love to be directed to other sources that can flesh out the details missing in the above proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll fill in some details.

Let's prove that $|A|$ is compact given the finite-dimensional assumption on its spectral projections.  If the $P_{[a, \infty)}$ were all finite dimensional, then they'd be compact, so the operators $|A|P_{[a, \infty)}$ are also all compact, since $K(H)$, the collection of compact operators, is an ideal.  Now we see that $|A|$ can written as a limit of some compact operators.  But $K(H)$ is closed in $B(H)$, so $|A|$ is therefore compact.

Something worth mentioning: the statement you're trying to prove is only true if $H$ is separable (i.e. has countable dimension).  So we can construct your isometry as follows.  Choose $\{f_i\}$ a countable basis for the range of $P$ (assumed infinite dimensional) and $\{e_i\}$ a countable basis for $H$.  Then $e_i \mapsto f_i$ is your desired isometry.

Comment: Indeed, the latter statement is the more general fact that given any two infinite-dimensional separable Hilbert spaces, there is an isometric isomorphism between them.  "There is only one infinite-dimensional separable Hilbert space."

Comment: Thank you so much! I definitely should've been able to figure out the first one, but I think the whole idea of the spectral decomposition had me confused.

As for the second, I hadn't made the connection that separable $\to$ countable basis.

Does this mean that for self-adjoint operators there are only countably many eigenvectors (since eigenvectors corresponding to different eigenvalues are orthogonal)?