# Describe ideals in $\mathcal{L}(H)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

> Find all the closed ideals in $\mathcal{L}(H)$, where H - Hilbert space

I've seen [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663736/compact-operators-form-the-only-closed-proper-ideal-of-bounded-linear-operators), but in the condition of the theorem we use the restriction that A is not compact. I'm not sure, that it enough for my statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question you quote shows that if $H$ is separable, then the only nontrivial closed ideal is $K(H)$.

In general, you can play the same game in this way: let $\{e_j\}_{j\in J}$ be an orthonormal basis of $H$. We can see the compact operators as the closure of the finite-rank operators. Similarly, for any $J_0\subset J$, we can construct an ideal $I_{J_0}$ by taking the closure of the set of all operators of rank of dimension at most $|J_0|$. Two such ideals will be isomorphic if and only if the subsets have the same cardinality. Thus, for each cardinality which is at most $|J|$, we have a proper ideal. The proof that $I_{J_1}\subsetneq I_{J_2}$ goes exactly as [the one you quoted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663736/compact-operators-form-the-only-closed-proper-ideal-of-bounded-linear-operators)(or see a [slightly different proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1070875/22857)), replacing "finite-rank" with "rank at most $|J_1|$".

Comment: thank you for your answer. $J$ in this case it's still two-sided ideal from $\mathcal{L}(H)$?